# Raspberry Pi not recognizing PM2 and NPM when running startup script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, raspberry-pi, pm2

I'm trying to make my `Raspberry Pi` run an `Node.js` project on startup but since it's a server and I want to free the terminal I use `PM2`. The script works fine when run on its own but when I run it on startup (as it's supposed to be run) I get this log:

```bash
/[PROJECT DIR]/server/serverScript.sh: line 21: npm: command not found
PM2 Update Successful
/[PROJECT DIR]/server/serverScript.sh: line 24: pm2: command not found
```

Here's my current script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

colorOff='\033[0m'
boldRed='\033[1;31m'
boldGreen='\033[1;32m'

echoSuccess() {
        echo -e "${boldGreen}$1${colorOff}"
}

# echoFailure() {
#         echo -e "${boldRed}$1${colorOff}"
# }

set -e

exec > >(tee "/[PROJECT DIR]/server/server.log") 2>&1

cd /[PROJECT DIR]/server

npm install pm2@latest -s -g && pm2 update -s
echoSuccess "PM2 Update Successful"

pm2 kill -s
pm2 save -s --force

git pull origin main -q
echoSuccess "Git Pull Successful"

npm install -s
echoSuccess "NPM Install Successful"

pm2 start -s --name "Server" "./index.js"
echoSuccess "PM2 Start Successful"

pm2 start -s --name "Ngrok" "ngrok http 8393"
echoSuccess "NGROK Start Successful"

pm2 save -s --force

sleep 2

url=`curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels -s | jq -r '.tunnels[0].public_url'`

echo "NGROK URL: "$url
```

**Edit:**
After a bit of searching around I was actually able to find the answer to my question. All I had to do was add `source /home/[user]/.nvm/nvm.sh` to my script.

Comment: When it's not running in your normal shell environment, it won't have any additions you make to that environment in your shell initialization files (~/.bashrc etc). The `npm` and `pm2` are probably in some directory that isn't in the normal `PATH`, so you'll need to add them within the script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Could you tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to make the script self-sufficient, not dependent on your shell environment. At the very least, it needs to be able to find the `npm` and `pm2` programs. You can find where they are by running `which npm` and `which pm2`. Then either modify the script to use explicit paths to them (e.g. `/path/to/npm install ...`), or have the script add their directories to `PATH` (e.g. `PATH="$PATH:/path/to`) before trying to use them. There may be other environment dependencies that you need to find and correct as well.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried your solution and it still didn't work. How can I test if my script is self sufficient? What else could cause such a problem (since it doesn't seem to be the PATH)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I actually was able to solve the issue myself. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ProGamer2711 Would you mind sharing your experience on how you were able to solve the issue? It could be helpful for others who may encounter a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I edited the post to add my solution.